# How to tell gnuplot not to print fit log on screen?

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I'm writing a bash script that, among several more things, calls gnuplot to fit a few data files. When it does so my terminal gets flooded with the gnuplot fit log.

I do not want that, I'd like that gnuplot just kept the fit log to the file 'fit.log', rather than printing it on screen. But I can't find a gnuplot command to prevent the fit log file from being printed on terminal.

How can I redirect all gnuplot text output to a file because I would like to know just by looking at the terminal whether it returned any errors.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The option you want is

```
set fit quiet
```

This will still make the `fit.log` file.  If you don't want to create the file either, you can

```
set fit logfile '/dev/null'
```